# Make call to generic class nested function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, system.reflection

I have `Repository<T>` where `T` is derrived form of `BaseEntity` class.
`Repository<T>` has  `IQueryable<T> Table` property. I need to make a call to `FirstOrDefault` method in the `Table` property.

till now i have got to list the Repositories, but stuck making call to the method using reflection.

```
private IEnumerable<object> GetEnumerableRepositoryOf<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class
        {
            List<object> objects = new List<object>();
            foreach (Type type in
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes()
                .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
            {                
                objects.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(type), constructorArgs));
            }
            return objects;
        }

var repoList = GetEnumerableRepositoryOf<BaseEntity>(constructorArgs);
foreach (var repo in repoList)
        {               
            // call FirstOrDefault() here
        }
```

Comment: What the reason doing so strange?

Comment: To get 1st record from every repository ofcourse.  :v

Comment: reflection has a cost , whats the idea behind implementing this

Comment: Why returning an `IEnumerable<object>` when you can return an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: What I think of is you should have `FirstOrDefault` inside Base Repo and then you can call with type `T`

Comment: @vishalsharma it is not for frequent use, I am testing db consistency without migration.

Comment: @ZoharPeled making object to T gives type casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your list is `Repository<X>` where `X` is `T`, and the property Table is `IQueryable<X>`. As we are lacking type knowledge of `X` at compile time, reflection it is.

So get the property with reflection by using the non-generic interface, then apply cast to `T`, and do your FirstOrDefault.

Here's how you can do it:

```
foreach (var repo in repoList)
{
  var firstOrNull = 
    (repo.GetType().GetProperty("Table").GetValue(repo) as IQueryable)
      .Cast<BaseEntity>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If using entity framework (which does not support this kind of casting above):

```
foreach (var repo in repoList)
{
  var enumerator = 
    (repo.GetType().GetProperty("Table").GetValue(repo) as IEnumerable)
      .GetEnumerator();

  var firstOrNull = (BaseEntity) (enumerator.MoveNext() ? 
        enumerator.Current : default(BaseEntity));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answers. However i am getting cast error `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types` I tried using `object` instead of `BaseEntity` too but its the same. Anyway we can get over it?

Comment: You should consider mentioning the that you use entity framework in your question, at least use a tag. I have added an alternative method in my answer that might work for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with some tweak it worked great. There still was Casting error during `MoveNext` so I added some edits.

Comment: I do see 1 problem with this, its going to load all the records at start.

Comment: Well it really shouldn't. did you confirm this? MoveNext should only read the first returned record from the underlying provider, unless its implementation is broken.

Comment: Hmm, actually you are missing `()` after MoveNext.